# JQuery attr not changing dialog title

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

We have this JQuery code:

`$('#dialog-message').attr("title", t);`

It works fine the first time it's executed - the title is changed.  But on subsequent calls to this method the title is not updated.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change the title of the dialog not the title attribute of the HTML Element:

$('#dialog-message').dialog( "option" , 'title' , 'new Title' )